# D3 Line Graph - Line is not plotting at the right co-ordinates

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to plot a line graph in D3 giving some co-ordinates. But I don't know why the line is not plotting at the right co-ordinates.

For example the first point is (4,2), but it starts from (0,2) and so on. I might be wrong somewhere. Please see below snap:

[image]

Here's a stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-n1ueun?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Here's the code:

```
maxAllowed = 60;
  graphData = [
    {
      hrCount: 4,
      resCount: 2
    },
    {
      hrCount: 8,
      resCount: 5
    },
    {
      hrCount: 12,
      resCount: 10
    },
    ...
const margin = { top: 25, right: 25, bottom: 25, left: 25 };
    const width =
      document.getElementById("svgcontainer").parentElement.offsetWidth -
      (margin.left + margin.right);
    const height =
      document.getElementById("svgcontainer").parentElement.offsetHeight -
      (margin.top + margin.bottom);

    // Remove any existing SVG
    d3.select("#svgcontainer")
      .selectAll("svg > *")
      .remove();

    // Group
    const g = d3
      .select("#svgcontainer")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ", " + margin.top + ")");

    // Scale
    // x-scale
    const xScale = d3
      .scaleBand()
      .domain(this.graphData.map((d: any) => d.hrCount))
      .range([0, width]);
    // y-scale
    const yScale = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, this.maxAllowed])
      .range([height, 0]);

    // y-axis gridline
    g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y-axis-grid")
      .call(
        d3
          .axisLeft(yScale)
          .tickSize(-width)
          .tickFormat("")
          .ticks(5)
      );

    // Axis
    // x-axis
    const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickSizeOuter(0);
    g.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + height + ")")
      .attr("class", "graph-axis")
      .call(xAxis.scale(xScale))
      .append("text")
      .attr("x", width)
      .attr("y", -6)
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("font", "10px sans-serif")
      .attr("letter-spacing", "1px")
      .attr("fill", "#8997b1")
      .text("Hours");
    // y-axis
    const yAxis = d3
      .axisLeft(yScale)
      .ticks(5)
      .tickSizeOuter(0);
    g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "graph-axis")
      .call(yAxis.scale(yScale))
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("font", "10px sans-serif")
      .attr("letter-spacing", "1px")
      .attr("fill", "#8997b1")
      .text("Resources");

    // Data line
    const line = d3
      .line()
      .x((d: any) => xScale(d.hrCount))
      .y((d: any) => yScale(d.resCount));
    const path = g
      .append("path")
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "#088dda")
      .attr("stroke-width", "2px")
      .attr("d", line(this.graphData));
    // Transition
    const totalLength = path.node().getTotalLength();
    path
      .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
      .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength);
    path
      .transition()
      .duration(4000)
      .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);

    // Data dots
    g.selectAll("line-circle")
      .data(this.graphData)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("r", 4)
      .attr("fill", "#088dda")
      .attr("cx", (d: any) => xScale(d.hrCount))
      .attr("cy", (d: any) => yScale(d.resCount));
  }
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Don't use band scales for quantitative variables, use a linear scale instead: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kzph2f?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thanks but I also need to show the same x-axis values as given in the data. With this the scale is divided with the multiple of 5 values. I tried 'ticks(15)' but that doesn't divide the values as expected. Kindly help. Thanks.

Comment: If you absolutely have to use `scaleBand` (which you shouldn't, as @Gerardo Furtado pointed out), one way to centre the points is to use `.x((d: any) => xScale(d.hrCount) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2)`.

Comment: @RubenHelsloot It works. But also I will try to implement it with linear scale. Thanks